# Jquery mobile error styling issue

Tags: html, css, validation, jquery-mobile, stylesheet

I am using jquery mobile exact folloiwng example:
http://www.raymondcamden.com/demos/2012/jul/30/round3/register.html

if you run this in a desktop browser or wide screen it displays empty field validation error 
that has wrong styling in case of textfields except dropdown.

any one guide me how to fix this issue? in short i want to display error below each field either it is small screen or wider one.(see attached screenshot)[image]

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post error messages code? It's possible to append the error msgs after `label` but I need to check the rendered markup by JQM.

Comment: <label for="email" generated="true" class="error" style="">This field is required.</label>

Comment: it is generated below input field automatically and inside container              <fieldset data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="required email" minlength="5">
   </fieldset>

Comment: you can also inspect that url through Firebug,or inspection tool.

Comment: Try this, give error labels class `ui-input-text`. I'm using iPad now, it's somehow difficult to get exact position of input labels.

Comment: putting this class displays error box below label but not below textbox and vertical aligned to it.

Comment: I thought this is what you wanted. I'll look at it again..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up this issue by finding another two very good tutorials:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/jquery-mobile-forms/
http://leepowers.net/files/jqmv/examples/after.html

that are easily modifiable through css and jquery.

might help someone.